# Google custom search autocomplete only on selected words

Tags: search-engine, custom-search-provider

I wish to use [Google custom search](http://www.google.com/cse/) and in particular would like to have the autocompletions functionality.

However I don't want it to suggest autocompletions for just anything, but rather only for a selected list of words I have (i.e. all the page titles of my website).

Does anyone know of a good way of doing this? I would have assumed there was a 'google regular expression' that would add all autocompletions to the excluded list, and then you could add your own to the included list, and it would only work with them.

At the moment autocompletions is on, but I cannot get it to suggest words I put in the included list (there is nothing in the excluded lists). The [help page](http://www.google.com/support/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182256) I found was not as helpful as I had hoped.

So if anyone understands how autocompletions work on Google custom search I would greatly appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service from [AutoCompletePlus.com](http://www.AutoCompletePlus.com) seems to be addressing your need - right?

Comment: That does indeed look like a solution. In end I personally bypassed Google and used the JqueryUI Autocomplete widget: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/